# Not able to return gridview with values

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to dynamically return a search box which will give product names in the table based on the SQL like function using parameterised addwithvalue function.

My aspx design file looks like this:

[image]

My code behind aspx.cs code is this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace KUD4
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from dbo.tblProductInventory where ProductName like @ProductName", connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", TextBox1.Text + "%");
                connection.Open();
                GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

When I try to enter any text in the search field and click Get Product button. The gridview does not arrive.

What am I doing wrong?

My table is this:

```
id  ProductName QuantityAvailable
101 iPhone  101
102 Apple Laptops   100
103 Books   120
104 Acer Laptops    119
105 iPads   134
```

Comment: `ExecuteReader` returns `SqlDataReader` which doesn't support any of `IList`, `IListSource`, `IBindingList` or `IBindingListView` as `DataSource` property requiers.

Comment: whats the solution then in the code

Comment: it was working before when it was not parameterised I think the issue lies with the parameterised code not with gridview

Comment: Another problem could be a type mismatch when `AddWithValue` autodetects type by the provided value. Suppose the column type is `Nvarchar` while autodetected type is `Varchar`. Provide explicit type for the parameter matching db column type.

Comment: its varchar in the table how would you change it please give an example let me try it

Comment: Don't use `AddWithValue` https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/

Answer (score 0):

What you have looks quite good. However, it probably a good idea to FORCE the data type in the parameter.

I thus suggest you try this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text + "%";
```

While the compiler will complain if you use "add" with 3 values - that's deprecated. But a .Add() with two values - strong data typed, and using .Value as per above is not in any way deprecated, and in fact is a good approach.

And quite nice is if you don't enter anything into that text box and hit your search button, it should show all rows.

Also, no problem with shoving + using .ExecuteReader right into the grid as you done.

However, do keep in mind that if you have a data pager, then you have to add this:

```
DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
rstData.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader);
GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

However, without a datapager - what you have is fine and should work.

And one more FYI:

You done great - since the sql cmd object has a data reader - you don't need a separate one as so many examples show - you avoided that - good for you!

However, the sql command object ALSO has a connection object!!! So, you don't need a separate one of those either! And of course the sql cmd object also has a parameters object too - don't need a separate one of those!

Not a big deal, but the result then is you can do this:

```
string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBCS").ConnectionString;

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from dbo.tblProductInventory where ProductName like @ProductName", 
     new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text + "%";
    cmd.Connection.Open();

    GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

So the sql command object has all 3 things you need in one great little object. And that also means you can pass this to other routines etc., or just sleep warm and happy that this object in fact has all 3 things you need. A reader, a command, and a connection object, and also the parameters (hum, that's 4 things!).